# How can I fill array with model properties in controller action and pass to view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a table namely Resource that consist of multiple properties. I want define an array and fill that with Id,Latitude and Longitude properties in action namely DistanceMCalculate() in controller and pass this array to javascript in view in my MVC project.

This is my model in edmx:

```
public partial class Resource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartHour { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Arrivetime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ArriveTimeDuration { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProgressPercent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ResourceTypeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Latitude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Longitude { get; set; }

        public virtual ResourceType ResourceType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And  this is my action and I want add Id,Latitude and Longitude properties of model to an array(arraylist) and pass to view in javascript. I need just array in view.how can I do it?

```
public ActionResult DistanceMCalculate()
        {
            var model= db.Resource.Where(p => p.ResourceTypeId == 1 && p.Latitude != null).ToList();

            return Json();
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which version ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: I am using  MVC5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public decimal?[][] DistanceMCalculate()
        {
            var result= db.Resource
                .Where(p => p.ResourceTypeId == 1 && p.Latitude != null)
                .Select(x => new decimal?[] { x.Id, x.Latitude, x.Longitude })
                .ToArray();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203825/discussion-on-answer-by-hadi-how-can-i-fill-array-with-model-properties-in-contr).